# Pure C. Dll export

Tags: c, dll, header, linker

I'm working on a simple project, which I want to be compiled into a DLL.
But I'm having problems with headers.
In my `Main.c` I have `#include "Main.h"` which looks like this:

```
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)

MYDLL_API  int A(byte * Dst, char * FileName);
MYDLL_API  int B(byte * Dst, char * FileName);
```

But the compiler reports errors:

```
error: missing ")" before "*"
error: missing "{" before "*"
error: "type"
error: ")"
```

If I put "`MYDLL_API`" into brackets I get "type" error only.
P.S. I've tried many _decl,__declspec and _declspec weird combinations, but never reached the goal.
P.S. IDE is VS2010.

Comment: Where is `byte` defined?

Comment: @chux Omg, so stuped. byte was defined a bit farther. You can post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code does not define `byte` before using it.